# Check Div by if it contains certain strings then Hide other div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to check by div id if div contains certain words then hide other div by its id.

Like this snippet - http://jsfiddle.net/EwpWA/211/

My example

`<div id="search-result-data">NO Result</div>`

`<div id="navigationbottom">Hide this content</div>`

If div search-result-data contains word `NO Result` then hide div navigationbottom

How we can achive this with php or jquery

Comment: Is there php code? to display div value. if there is  PHP code then show your code

Comment: no php code to show. all results in div `search-result-data` comes from jquery

Comment: [See](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: Not working above link

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```js
if ($("#search-result-data:contains('NO Result')").length)
  $("#navigationbottom").hide();
else
  $("#navigationbottom").show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search-result-data">NO Result</div>
<div id="navigationbottom">Hide this content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below helps

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    str = $('#search-result-data').text();
    if(str.indexOf("NO Result") >= 0){
       $('#navigationbottom').hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search-result-data">NO Result</div>

<div id="navigationbottom">Hide this content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an easy solution, hope it helps:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div").each(function(){
        if($(this).html() == "No Result"){
       $(this).hide()
        }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="search-result-data">No Result</div>

<div id="navigationbottom">Hide this content</div>
</body>
```